# error: resource android:style/TextAppearance.Material not found

Tags: android, api, resources

I am using API 23 and I'm trying to get it to API 19.

I changed the manifest to :

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:noHistory="true">
```

And I have changed the gradle build to

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 19
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.force 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9'
}
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "hi_there"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 19
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    multiDexEnabled true

}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
productFlavors {
}
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud:conversation:4.2.1'
    compile 'com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud:text-to-speech:4.2.1'
    compile 'com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud:speech-to-text:4.2.1'
    compile 'com.ibm.mobilefirstplatform.clientsdk.android:analytics:1.1.0'
    compile 'com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud:android-sdk:0.4.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    compile 'com.estimote:sdk:1.4.1'
    compile 'com.estimote:mustard:0.2.1'

    compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.10.3'
    compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.9.4'
    // for joda
    compile 'pub.devrel:easypermissions:0.3.0'
    compile('com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.23.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
    }
    compile('com.google.apis:google-api-services-calendar:v3-rev276-1.23.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
    }
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
```

I have also tried

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:19.0.0'
```

which leads to

```
"Failed to resolve: com.android.support:design:19.0.0"
```

I have a feeling that the problem in .xml files I have created.
I am using full-screen activities for all of my .xml files

any feedback is appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Material Design is available from API Level 21.

You should replace

```
compileSdkVersion 19
targetSdkVersion 19
```

To

```
compileSdkVersion 21
targetSdkVersion 21
```

It will work then.

Also use 21.0.0 version for design library.

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:21.0.0'
```

hope it will help you. :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply :)

When I changed

```
compileSdkVersion 21
targetSdkVersion 21
```

I ended up getting this

[image: sdk_21]
When I added

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:21.0.0'
```

I ended up getting this

[image: design_21_sdk]

it seems like the minimum sdk it is working on is 23